# can't load package kknn in r studio

Tags: r, package, load

[image]

looks like the package has been successfully installed, however, the below message keeps appearing:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘kknn’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘lattice’

The `kknn` package was successfully installed before today. But I can't knit the document to pdf, so I installed a package called `latexpdf`. After that, the whole RStudio just doesn't function well. I don't know what happened... tried to re-install but doesn't help.

Does anyone know what should I do with this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the modification!

I installed `Lattice` package and the problem solved...what a silly question...